# list() constructor with list?

Tags: python, nltk

I'm new in Python and I don't understand the purpose of `list()` function in this piece of code:

```
documents = [(list(movie_reviews.words(fileid)), category)
              for category in movie_reviews.categories()
              for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category)]
```

The method `words()` is already returning a list of tokenized words from a string, and I don't see any difference between that and

```
documents = [(movie_reviews.words(fileid), category)
              for category in movie_reviews.categories()
              for fileid in movie_reviews.fileids(category)]
```

Comment: It likely *has* no purpose. Whoever wrote it may not have though that `words` already returned a list (rather than a generator, for example), or they though it necessary to make a copy of the list.

Comment: This creates a copy of the list object. This is useful when `words()` continues to keep the same list object it returns (e.g. for caching purposes). Without copying, the `document` variable will share the references to the same list as `words()`, which is bug-prone if any holder of the references modifies the list, when the other holder does not expect it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three possibilities:

1. It is a mistake, no call to `list()` is required.
2. The interface only guarantees that the method returns an `Iterable` type, which may be any one of: list, set, iterator, generator, etc. The specific `movie_reviews.words()` may return a list today, but either that may change in future versions, or in other classes with similar interfaces (child/parent/or simply similar interface).

   Whether this is the case, should be stated explicitly in the documentation, or could be gleamed out of the inheritance hierarchy.
3. The method performs some sort of memoization, while keeping a copy of the returned list. A good practice would be to copy the cached-list inside the method, but maybe they returned a shared list-object.

   If the method returns a reference to a shared list object, then it is a good idea to call `list()`, in order to create a new list object. Without the copy operation, any change to the `list` by one side (inside the method vs. through `documents` variable) will confuse the other side. If you change the list through `documents` varaible, then calling `movie_reviews.words(fileid)` with the same `fileid` may return the wrong value.

   In general, although this is bad design, this happens in real code. I once had to debug such an issue in live code. Usually, in case of memoization, it is better to return an immutable type such as a tuple, instead of a list, which will guarantee both speed and safety.